# "Your request failed to complete", but nothing in log: How to investigate further

Tags: liferay

In Liferay, I see the following error:

[image: Your request failed to complete]

Problem: Absolutely nothing appear in the Liferay log

Question: How to investigate further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some obscure reason, Liferay has chosen to make some exceptions (even very serious ones) show up with the DEBUG log level.

So, the solution is to set the log level to DEBUG (The `com.liferay` package should be enough for most situations):

[image: Liferay log level]

Don't forget to press "Save". Once set, try again (no restart needed), and you will probably see the exception appear, so that you can know exactly what is going wrong.

Example:

```
09:34:29,903 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-5][LiferayPortlet:587] com.liferay.asset.kernel.exception.NoSuchEntryException: No AssetEntry exists with the key {classNameId=20015, classPK=36354}
com.liferay.asset.kernel.exception.NoSuchEntryException: No AssetEntry exists with the key {classNameId=20015, classPK=36354}
        at com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.persistence.impl.AssetEntryPersistenceImpl.findByC_C(AssetEntryPersistenceImpl.java:3551)
```

This log level modification will be reset next time you restart Liferay.

Comment: how the heck did you get that??

Answer (score 0):

To get more information on an unexpected *"Your request failed to complete"* error, you can activate the DEBUG traces for the category:

- `com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionErrors`

on the *Control Panel => System => Server Administration => Log levels* section.

After activating these DEBUG traces, every time an error is stored in the SessionErrors object, it will be written to the log file.

These traces were added by the [LPS-135569](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-135569) issue that was fixed as of DXP 7.4, so if you are using an older version, you will have to update or patch your installation.